# User processes killed at specific time of day

Tags: 20.04, cron, process

I am running python scripts fetching data and putting it into a database that take up to a day or maybe even longer on Ubuntu 20.04 headless like so:

`` stdbuf -o0 -e0 -i0 /path/v3_start_fetch.sh >> /path/logs/v3_cronlog_start_fetch__`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`___.log 2>&1 & ``

The script:

```
. /path/env_project_auto/bin/activate

cd  /path/working_scripts

python -u v3_updater_direct.py
```

Every exception will also be logged into the MySQL Database.

**Problem:** Every time I run any script (I tried a few different ones), it seems to stop at exactly the same time, which is 23:36. There is the last log entry (log entries are made multiple per second). It doesn't matter if the script ran one hour or 15 hours prior, stop time is always the same.

In the syslog there seems to be suspicious things pointing to the problem, but I can make no sens of what it is, because all the entries regarding `Stopping User Manager for UUID xxx` seem to be having to do with NVidia booting problems like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426235/how-to-solve-stopping-user-manager-for-uid-121-error-after-installing-nvidia-d), while [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248711/ubuntu-server-16-04-log-stopping-user-manager-for-uid-1002) is unanswered.

The log entry:

```
Oct 30 23:25:01 torbenserver02 CRON[12977]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Oct 30 23:26:01 torbenserver02 CRON[12986]: (torben) CMD (echo "`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`: `dig +short torben.ddns.net`" >> /home/torben/Projects/ip.log)
Oct 30 23:26:08 torbenserver02 systemd[1]: session-975.scope: Succeeded.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Stopped target Main User Target.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Stopped target Basic System.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Stopped target Paths.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Stopped target Sockets.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Stopped target Timers.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: dbus.socket: Succeeded.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: dirmngr.socket: Succeeded.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: gpg-agent-browser.socket: Succeeded.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: gpg-agent-extra.socket: Succeeded.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: gpg-agent-ssh.socket: Succeeded.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: gpg-agent.socket: Succeeded.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: pk-debconf-helper.socket: Succeeded.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Closed debconf communication socket.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: snapd.session-agent.socket: Succeeded.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Reached target Shutdown.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: systemd-exit.service: Succeeded.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Finished Exit the Session.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[11289]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Succeeded.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[1]: run-user-1000.mount: Succeeded.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@1000.service: Succeeded.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
Oct 30 23:26:18 torbenserver02 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Oct 30 23:27:01 torbenserver02 CRON[13038]: (torben) CMD (echo "`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`: `dig +short torben.ddns.net`" >> /home/torben/Projects/ip.log)
Oct 30 23:28:01 torbenserver02 CRON[13046]: (root) CMD (   test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond)
```

**EDIT** The DB is running locally and no backups are configured. It seems to happen some arbitrary time after I close all SSH shells, usually around 1-2 hours. It happened at very different times during the day when I stopped working in the afternoon this weekend. Also it does not seem to happen when I run jobs via the terminal directly on the machine. So I did what is described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545195/systemd-service-does-not-last-more-than-6-hours), and will try to reproduce teh bug to see if it helped.

Comment: Could the database be being shutdown for backup at 23:35? Also `cron` isn't `bash`. Using `bash`isms on the `crontab` line leads to eventual disaster. Wrap your `bash` in a script, and call that from `crontab`. Beware `$PATH` and environment (`env`) differences.

Comment: Thanks for the ```cron``` vs ```bash``` note. I will update as soon as I tried if the fix worked. Or does it look like something else to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this `loginctl enable-linger *username*` found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545195/systemd-service-does-not-last-more-than-6-hours) keeps my processes running.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [GNU Screen](https://www.howtogeek.com/662422/how-to-use-linuxs-screen-command/) when I want my session to persist on a server even after I close my SSH session. It should keep your session active on the server and then prevent systemd from killing it.